# NSDate and NSDateFormatter not my current local or string date

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I read all about `NSDate` and `NSDateFormatter` but nothing solve my problem. I need to get my current date, and mont this date in NSDate object, but when i do this, my hour always came with +2 hours. im doing something like that:

```
NSDateFormatter * dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateformatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss"];
//NSTimeZone* localTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
//NSLog(@"timezone local = %@",localTimeZone);
//[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"BRST"];
NSString * current = [dateformatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"current = %@",current); // Cool this is my current date!

NSDate *thedate = [dateformatter dateFromString:current]; 
NSLog(@"date = %@",thedate);// NO! my hours is wrong
```

i need to add my current date in `NSDate`, and also, need to add a `NSDate` with a string (with method `stringFromDate`). The string example: 2013-01-21 17:05:17. When pass this string in method `stringFromDate` returning NSDate, i print NSDate and bring me this wrong date: 2013-01-21 19:05:17 +0000.

Just a resume:

> Need to add into NSDate my current date and also need to add into `NSDate` with a `NSString` like 2013-01-21 17:05:17. My current local is Brasil/São paulo, and NSTimerZone abreviation is BRST.

Comment: When you instantiate a NSDate object, it's set to the current date by default. Your date is correct. The problem is that when you display its value by its description method (this is what is being called when you log it as @"%@"), you may be seing it with a different locale, and that's why you think it is not correct.
But you can try to format it again with that formatter and you will see that you get the same string (which will be what you expected).
So the general idea is to display NSDate always using the NSDateFormatter and not by its description message so you will not get confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`theDate` is correct, you just display it in another timezone (+0000).

NSDate objects doesn't know anything about time zones. But NSDateFormatter objects do know. By default NSDateFormatter uses current time zone (that the user set up in OS preferences).

When you create a string and display it, it is shown in your timezone BRST (-0200): 2013-01-21 17:05:17. Then when you create date from this string, date formatter treats it again as a date in BRST time zone. But when you display raw NSDate object, it shows date in +0000 time zone: 2013-01-21 19:05:17 +0000, which is 17:05:17 in BRST.

Comment: exactly! that was the problem and this was my conclusion about NSDate and NSDateFormatter. Thank you good answer

Answer (score 1):

It is because in your `dateformatter` you use `HH` instead of `hh`. Change it in your code to:

```
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"];
```

You can look for inmormation on this topic here:[link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)

> It uses yyyy to specify the year component. A common mistake is to use
>   YYYY. yyyy specifies the calendar year whereas YYYY specifies the year
>   (of “Week of Year”), used in the ISO year-week calendar. In most
>   cases, yyyy and YYYY yield the same number, however they may be
>   different. Typically you should use the calendar year.

Comment: i made the exchange with HH for hh but NSDate * date = [dateformatter dateFromString:@"2013-10-04 15:34:23"]; // return null.

Comment: NSString * current = [dateformatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSLog(@"current = %@",current); // current date still plus 2 hours of my current date

Comment: NSString * current = [dateformatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]; //current date = 2013-49-14 03:49:36 mouth 49 ???

Comment: I think it also should be MM for the month...That is 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'

Comment: current date now its ok! but with a string still get a return null! NSDate * date = [dateformatter dateFromString:@"2013-10-04 15:34:23"]; // return null. This date is coming from my database. Do i need to convert this date to hh? cuz the hours is 0-24 and hh is 0-12 !

Comment: I don't know why you are so confuse. I am sure that the date which you are getting if you will try to change it again in nsstring using same formatter then this will give you same result.

Comment: Use 24 hours date formatter. Because formatter style and your string style should be same.

Comment: i dont know why, but when using hh, my current date is ok! but when i use a method dateFromString:@"2013-10-04 15:34:23" return me null. So if i change hh to HH now i return to problem that I'm not getting current date with [NSDate date] but using  dateFromString:@"2013-10-04 15:34:23" works fine. Why?

Comment: solved!!! to get current date i need in NSDate i need to initialize like this: NSDate*wrongDate = [NSDate date]; NSDate *date = [NSDate alloc]initWithTimeInterval:-7200 sinceDate:wrongDate]; its exactly what i needed. And with both helps i understand about the difference between yyyy YYYY mm MM dd DD and hh HH !!! Thank you all!!

Comment: And you use "hh" or "HH" depending on whether you want a 12-hour or 24-hour clock.  Normally, if you're not displaying AM/PM (with one of the "a" indicators) you'd use "HH".

Comment: yes this was the first problem about NSDateFormatter.. i didnt understand what the difference between h H y Y d D m M and its very important to when you are formatting a data, and don't forget time zones...it took me to understand what @Alexei Kuznetsov said. Thank you everybody.